# В голове понимаю, но написать в коде не понимаю как

Tags: c, массивы, арифметика

Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при вводе числа ,например 12345, вывод был равен суме 1+2+3+4+5=15 и потом 1+5=6. Язык Си. Большое спасибо за ответ! Не могу придумать как сделать это. Тоесть в голове понимаю, но написать в коде не понимаю как.

Мой пример, но наверное он ничего не даст

```
    #include <stdio.h>
            int main(){
                int isicc >= 0;
                printf ("Enter a cislo isic: ");
                while (n>0){
                 int d =n%10; 
                   n=n /10;
                }
                scanf ("%d", &isicc);
                if isicc >=0             
            
            
                }
            }
```

Comment: Не нужно с другого аккаунта задавать один и тот же вопрос! Этот код который вы выложили, я не могу даже назвать попыткой решения, так что идите учить основы!!!

Comment: Я тогда не успел редактировать, извините

Comment: Да что там писать! Считываете (только не пишите бреда `int isicc >= 0;`), находите с помощью операции `%` остаток от деления на 9 - вот и есть ваше число. Разве что если получился 0, а исходное число не 0 - добавить 9...

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Уже лучше), но основы почитайте и увидите типичные ошибки.  По типу `int isicc >= 0` или `if isicc >= 0` (это не питон). Сначала создаете переменную `int isicc;` , потом считываете  `scanf` потом разбиваете его на цифры, это цикл в вашем коде, но он должен работать не с `n` которой нет, а с `isicc`. Переменную `d` нужно складывать в переменную за циклом например `sum`, а потом разбивать уже эту сумму на цифры.

Comment: Да, возможно путаю с python, так как начинал свой путь с него)